# Swift - Can't understand float to string handling

Tags: string, swift

I've been dipping my toes into the waters of OS X development in X-Code using Apple's new Swift language. I feel as though I understand the basics and reading through the guide makes it seem much like Python to me at least. However I'm having a hard time sorting out even the most basic of algorithms.

I've tried to create a simple addition function for a calculator style application. I'm not seeing any errors and it builds just fine but isn't working for me... What am I missing??

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

@IBOutlet var window: NSWindow

@IBOutlet var InputA : NSTextField

@IBOutlet var InputB : NSTextField

@IBOutlet var Ouptut : NSTextField

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@IBAction func Addition(sender : AnyObject) {
    var result : Float =  InputA.floatValue + InputB.floatValue
    Ouptut.stringValue = String(result)

}

@IBAction func Subtraction(sender : AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func Division(sender : AnyObject) {
}

}
```

Comment: Swift really is not like python at all. A better mindset is "it's like C, but modern". Unlike Python this language does require at least cursory knowledge of how the hardware actually works. Also Apple's general philosophy is to improve performance at the expense of almost everything else, so this does add some workload to the programmer when you do things like type conversion - which is a slow operation that should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a new string from a `Float` using format, like this:

```
Ouptut.stringValue = String(format: "%.4f", result)
```

or by string interpolation, like this:

```
Ouptut.stringValue = "\(result)"
```

Comment: But when I attempt to run it, the program still crashes and gives me this: http://imgur.com/c3iTI9c

Comment: @user3185748 The picture does not look like crash, it looks like you have a breakpoint set on that line.

Comment: Oh my goodness.... well that explains a lot... Thank you! So I found out how to continue with the program, but how do I remove the breakpoint? Now that I know the function works it would be a bit of a pain for it to stop there every time.

Comment: @user3185748 Command-click the breakpoint, and choose "delete breakpoint".

Comment: I just figured that out as you posted, thank you so much! Glad to finally have it working, have a great evening.